# Running Flash Player on Headless Linux Server

Tags: linux, flash, xorg, xvfb

Warning: I'm not that good at using Linux, so be easy on me.

I'm running a CentOS 6 x64 Server. I have a swf designed to generate complex images on command. I did a lot of searching, and the best answer I could find is install Xvfb and Flash Player to run the SWF.

So I installed Xvfb fine, and downloaded the standalone flash player debugger for Linux. I use

```
 xvfb-run ./flashplayerdebugger screenapp.swf
```

to generate the image. Flash player debugger is designed for x86, and was throwing an error. I googled it, and found a page telling me to install the x86 dependencies. I did it, and the errors are gone. Unfortunately the swf doesn't seem to work on the server. For testing purposes it contacts a php file which creates a text file, so I know it's working, which works fine on my Windows computer for testing.

All it does is after I run the command is hang, after waiting a bit nothing still happens. I'm not sure if it's supposed to be like that, but it's not running the simple code I have on the swf to just load a URL

```
[root@ms1 ~]# xvfb-run ./flashplayerdebugger screenapp.swf
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 xvfb-run ./flashplayerdebugger screenapp.swf
```

I'm no Linux expert, but the test SWF works fine on Windows, just can't get it to run on Linux. If the problem is flashplayerdebugger, how can I install the correct flash player?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
xvfb-run +extension RANDR ./flashplayerdebugger screenapp.swf
```

Also, I found that its very useful that in Linux you can just copy-paste any console error or message by ctrl+shift+c (various for different consoles) and just google about it possible solutions.

Comment: xvfb-run doesn't appear to support "+extension". However, the underlying xvfb does, so the following works

`xvfb-run -s "+extension RANDR" ./flashplayerdebugger screenapp.swf`